# NodeJS Callback and Return value confusion

Tags: node.js, callback, return

I need to find a way return a string to digest in my primary code block as well as a callback or something to start working on the rest of the code in my primary code block once the value for digest is returned.

Please Help!

Here is my current code that does not work.

```
var digest = checkIntegrity(filePath, res[3]);
//digest always come back undefined and never matches res[2] so file always deletes

if (digest === 0){
    console.log('File Inaccessible');
} else {
    if (digest === res[2]){
        createNewFile();
    } else {
        console.log('File hash doesn't match');
        delBadFile();
    }
}

function checkIntegrity(filePath, algorithm, cb){
    console.log('in checkIntegrity');
    var hash = crypto.createHash(algorithm);
    var digest;

    //see if file is there
    fs.stat(filePath, function(fileErr, fileStats){
        if(fileErr){
            //error accessing file, most likely file does not exist
            return 0;
        } else {
            //file exists
            var fileIn = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
            fileIn.on('data', function(chunk){
                if (chunk) {
                    hash.update(chunk);
                }
            });

            fileIn.on('end', function(){
                return hash.digest('hex');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're `checkIntegrity` function is asynchronous, i.e. it accepts a callback. Any value that you wish to pass as a result of that function should be passed as an argument to that callback function. What is happening in your example is that `checkIntegrity` is calling out to `fs.stat` (which is also asynchronous) and then returns `undefined` straightaway - before `fs.stat` has chance to complete.

You have a choice:

1. Change the call from `fs.stat` to [`fs.statSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_statsync_path). That is a synchronous version of the stat function.
2. Change your code to use callbacks properly:

   ```
   checkIntegrity(filePath, res[3], function (err, digest) { 
       if (err) return console.error(err);

       if (digest === 0) {
           console.log('File Inaccessible');
       } else {
           if (digest === res[2]){
               createNewFile();
           } else {
               console.log('File hash doesn\'t match');
               delBadFile();
           }
       }
   });

   function checkIntegrity(filePath, algorithm, cb){
       console.log('in checkIntegrity');
       var hash = crypto.createHash(algorithm);
       var digest;

       //see if file is there
       fs.stat(filePath, function(fileErr, fileStats) {
           if(fileErr){
                //error accessing file, most likely file does not exist
               return cb(fileErr);
           } else {
               //file exists
               var fileIn = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
               fileIn.on('data', function(chunk){
                   if (chunk) {
                       hash.update(chunk);
                   }
               });

               fileIn.on('end', function() {
                   cb(null, hash.digest('hes'));
               });
           }
       });
   }
   ```

In my opinion, asynchronous code and callbacks are such a fundamental part of Node.js I would encourage you to go for option 2. It is definitely worthwhile learning. There are hundreds of sites out there like [callbackhell.com](http://callbackhell.com/) that will do a much better job at explaining callbacks.